# Most appropriate way to update text in React Website?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, frontend

I have a react website running. Now the project managers and creatives want a method so that they can change the heading or the welcome messages on the website. Right now these have to go through me because I make these changes on the Front-end code and then I rebuild the website.

What methods are available for them to make these changes without involving me in between

One way is to give them a form in which they can make changes to the fields and then have an endpoint from which I'll download a json with the key-value pairs and that can be used for those changes.
I already have a database running, so this will be easier to implement too.

Is this a good way or can we have better methods?

Thanks.

Comment: The data will need to be stored somewhere and then retrieved and rendered... so yes your method is one of the ways of doing this..

Comment: Create a small API and a database on your backend, store key value pairs like "greeting", "Welcome to X", then retrieve them to render inside the app. Create a second app where they can log in and change the texts.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a fine approach, but if you already have a database set up (not sure if you do, but even otherwise) it seems it would be easier just to leverage a table from the database to store the messages. Create a `messages` table in the db and an admin panel in the frontend so that when they update a message, it posts to your backend which updates the corresponding message in the `messages` table. Then, your website, when loading the page, would make an API call to retrieve the messages and display these messages. If you want to account for loading time, you could show a default message at first and then update it once the data comes in from the API

Comment: I have a database set-up, so I think that'll be the best way to move forward.

Comment: @Clarskon yeah I would definitely recommend the database approach. I've done similar things in the past where I have a `meta` table or something of the sort that would store editable (by users) information important to the app's functioning